# Erro ao mostrar o resultado de um List utilizando MVC e JSF

Tags: jsf, hibernate, java-ee, mvc

Estou precisando retornar dados do banco de dados para JSF mas mesmo antes de chegar ao JSF não consigo mostrar os dados pesquisados.

Tenho Seguinte Erro:

```
Advertência:   #{usuarioBean.pesquisa}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
javax.faces.FacesException: #{usuarioBean.pesquisa}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
at br.com.atreu.dao.GenericDao.<init>(GenericDao.java:18)
at br.com.atreu.dao.UsuarioDao.retornoUsuarios(UsuarioDao.java:47)
at br.com.atreu.bean.UsuarioBean.pesquisa(UsuarioBean.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
... 35 more
```

Segue o código abaixo:

GenericDao:

```
public class GenericDao<T extends Serializable> {

private final Session session;
private final Class<T> persistentClass;

public GenericDao() {
    this.session = ConexaoUtil.getSession();
    this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType)
        getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

public Session getSession() {
    return session;
}

protected void save(T entity) {
    try {
        getSession().getTransaction().begin();
        getSession().save(entity);
        getSession().getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        getSession().getTransaction().rollback();
        t.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close();
    }
}

protected void update(T entity) {
    try {
        getSession().getTransaction().begin();
        getSession().update(entity);
        getSession().getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        getSession().getTransaction().rollback();
        t.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close();
    }
}

protected void delete(T entity) {
    try {
        getSession().getTransaction().begin();
        getSession().delete(entity);
        getSession().getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        getSession().getTransaction().rollback();
        t.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close();
    }
}

public List<T> findAll() throws Exception {
    return getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass).list();
}

public T findByName(String nome) {
    return (T) getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("nome", nome).ignoreCase()).uniqueResult();
}

public T findById(long id) {
    return (T) getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("id", id)).uniqueResult();
}

private void close() {
    if (getSession() != null && getSession().isOpen()) {
        getSession().close();
    }
}
}
```

UsuarioDao:

```
......
public List retornoUsuarios() throws Exception{

    GenericDao dao = new GenericDao();

    List<Usuario> lista = dao.findAll();

    return lista;
}
.......
```

UsuarioBean:

```
.......
public void pesquisa() throws Exception{

        UsuarioDao user = new UsuarioDao();
         List<Usuario> listaDeUsuario = user.retornoUsuarios();

        for (int i = 0; i < listaDeUsuario.size(); i++) {
            Usuario usuario = listaDeUsuario.get(i);

            System.out.println(usuario.getNome());

        }



    }
    .........
```

ListaUsuario.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org   /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"   
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Atreu System</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form> 

        <h:commandButton value="Gravar" action="#{usuarioBean.pesquisa}"/>

    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Comment: Acredito que o principal problema é apenas no `cast` entre o `java.lang.Class` e `java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType`. Não é propriamente um questão de `JSF`, `Java-EE`. Ainda estou a firmar bem a resposta, porém vejo que a impossibilidade esta esta conversão apenas.

Comment: @Cold Não entendi sua colocação pode detalhar melhor? Porém quis especificar que estou usando JSF e MVC pois não descartei a possibilidade de ser algo de problema ao chamar o método.

Comment: Pelo que observei no `stacktrace` o erro ocorre apenas na conversão de tipo e não propriamente na camada de apresentação. Não esta (in)diretamente relacionado com JSF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considere o seguinte trecho de código:

```java
this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType)
        getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

Isso está disponível em várias respostas do Stack Overflow, mas ele é algo muito inseguro. No cenário em questão, ele não vai funcionar.

## *Type erasure*

Primeiro, é preciso entender que a informação do tipo genérico de uma variável é removida em tempo de execução.

Por exemplo:

```java
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
```

O compilador "garante" que você só consiga adicionar objetos do tipo `String` dessa lista, mas quando sua classe é executada na JVM, não há qualquer verificação quanto ao tipo.

Sim, você pode dar um *cast* inseguro de `List<String>` para `List` e então adicionar outro objeto. O compilador vai aceitar, afinal ele "confia" em você.

Concluímos que é impossível para a instância `lista` saber o seu próprio tipo genérico, já que no fim das contas só existe uma única classe `ArrayList`, o tipo genérico é apenas um tipo de segurança para o desenvolvedor.

Li uma vez que manter o *Type Safety* implicaria em um *overhead* muito grande para a máquina virtual, pois o Java precisaria praticamente criar uma cópia da classe `List` para cada tipo genérico usado no programa.

## Quando é possível recuperar o tipo genérico

Existem cenários onde o código citado no início da resposta vai funcionar, mas precisamos prestar atenção aos detalhes.

Repare no método [`getGenericSuperclass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass--). Ele retorna os tipos que a classe atual define para os parâmetros genéricos da superclasse imediata. Algo análogo ocorre com o [`getGenericInterfaces()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericInterfaces--).

Isso significa que se você tiver uma subclasse assim:

```java
class UsuarioDao extends GenericDao<Usuario> { ... }
```

O código funcionaria perfeitamente, pois você está definindo um tipo para o parâmetro genérico da superclasse. Isso funciona porque o tipo genérico não está apenas numa variável, mas declarando de forma estática (fixa) na própria definição da classe.

Mas como você instancia diretamente o `GenericDao`, não há uma *generic superclass* e, portanto, a exceção sendo lançada.

## Basta usar herança?

Usar o exemplo com `extends` acima é uma saída, mas muitos não recomendam porque há chances do código "quebrar" com novos erros estranhos.

Essa é uma possibilidade, pois como a própria documentação do método `getGenericSuperclass()` afirma, ele só retorna o tipo genérico implementado da superclasse imediata da classe. Então se você tiver uma hierarquia diferente de exatamente dois níveis, o código vai falhar.

## Recomendação

A recomendação que vai funcionar de forma mais simples e direta é passar a classe desejada por parâmetro para o construtor do `GenericDao`.

Exemplo:

```java
public class GenericDao<T extends Serializable> {

    private final Class<T> persistentClass;

    public GenericDao(Class<T> persistentClass) {
        this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
    }

    .....
}
```

Muito mais simples, certo?

O maior inconveniente é a chamada *verbosa* de criação da classe:

```java
GenericDao<Usuario> usuarioDao = new GenericDao<Usuario>(Usuario.class);
```

## Evitando redundância

Para resolver isso, você pode criar um método *factory*. Exemplo:

```java
public class GenericDao<T extends Serializable> {

    final private Class<T> persistentClass;

    public static <X extends Serializable> GenericDao<X> getInstance(Class<X> persistentClass) {
        return new GenericDao<X>(persistentClass);
    }

    private GenericDao(Class<T> persistentClass) {
        this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
    }

    ...

}
```

E a criação da classe fica assim:

```java
GenericDao<Usuario> usuarioDao = GenericDao.getInstance(Usuario.class);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela bela explicação acima, além me ajudar com meu problema ajudou a entender alguns detalhes que não estavam muito claros.